# How do I get a handle to the VPC instance created by AWS-CDK ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService

Tags: aws-cdk

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_ecs_patterns/ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService.html), the Service;

> uses the VPC defined in the cluster or creates a new VPC.

But, there doesn't appear to be a property available to get at the newly created VPC. Since CDK mangles the name, getting it by lookup is also difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The VPC can be accessed via the cluster property of the services;

```
@property
def vpc(self) -> Vpc:
    return self._fargate.cluster.vpc
```